# Why Magento 2 Cloud integration and development environments are very slow?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, pagespeed, magento-cloud

My Magento 2 installation on production and staging is working well, but on development and integration environments the same code is very slow.

how could I find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because **production** and **staging** use their own environment. Your **development** and **integration** environments share a smaller capacity.

[image: Magento 2 Cloud infrastucture]

You can remove the cronjob setup in your integration and development environments, you can also run these commands below in your server, but the cronjobs will start again in the next deployment.

```
./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:kill
./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:disable
```